# commenting async in globals.js doesn't affect its usage in services

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, sails.js

Can someone give me some elementary tips about globals.js in sails.js, I have below questions.

1. I commented async in globals.js, I have removed async module which was installed in my project, now in a service I commented line //var async = require('async'); My code still works where ever I used async, I am new to sails and exploring the use of globals.js, is that like if async is commented any usage should throw an error "undefined".
2. How to add my own module to globals.js?
3. How is bootsrap.js different from global.js?

Appreciate your discussions and explanation.

Thanks

Comment: FYI, async is commented out by default in globals.js--in fact, practically every line of every config file in Sails is commented out by default.  The comments are there to _show you what the default values are_--in the case of globals.js, the commented-out value for `async` is `true`.  So, as Eugene states below, you have to uncomment it and set it to `false` to actually change the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `async` is module that exposed to global by Sails. Here is the code that responsible for it (full code here - https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/a210b48667708bea687dd5ec61ce9e07ffc0c005/lib/app/private/exposeGlobals.js#L35)

```
if (sails.config.globals.async !== false) {
  global['async'] = async;
}
```

You need to set `async` to `false` in `config/globals.js` and then you can't call `async`.

2) It's not a frameworks' question. You just make `global['myModule'] = myModule` but don't do this, please.

3) `bootstrap.js` is a function that calls before sails initialisation.

Comment: Also, [services](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/services) are globalized by default, so if you just want some code to be available globally, leave `services` alone in the `globals.js` file and go to town.

Comment: @Eugene Obrezkov can you help me in one practical example how to use bootstrap.js please, also is bootstrap.js a global. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so async is by default commented in globals.js and is available globally. When I uncommented that and set "async: false" I got the error I expected.

```
error: Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
ReferenceError: async is not defined
```